# jquery regex to match urls and email

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an existing php function to detect emails and url in a block message then replace it as it supposes to be. Now i need the same function in php but i couldn't get the regex right. can anyone help?

```
<?php
function replace_chat_tags($chat_body=''){
     $chat_body = preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?=\-&_/]+!', "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $chat_body);
     $chat_body = preg_replace('/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/si', "<a href=\"mailto:\\0\">\\0</a>", $chat_body);
     $chat_body = str_replace(array("&lt;br/&gt;"), "<br/>", $chat_body);
     return $chat_body;
 }
?>
```

**In js**

```
<script>
function replace_chat_tags(chat_body){
var chat_body;
  chat_body.replace(); //For urls
  chat_body.replace(); // Email Link
  chat_body.replace(); // I need this for a reason
  return chat_body;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You already have it in PHP, and now you need it in PHP? Something is wrong in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test regex things online with e.g. [regex101](https://regex101.com). It offers a JavaScript flavour too.

Anyway:

```js
function replace_chat_tags(chat_body = '') {
  return chat_body
    .replace( /((http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?=\-&_/]+)/g, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>" )
    .replace( /\b([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})\b/gi, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>" )
    .replace( /&lt;br\/&gt;/g, "<br/>" );
}

console.log( replace_chat_tags( 'hello http://www.google.com foo@bar.com&lt;br/&gt;foo&lt;br/&gt;' ) );
```

Don't forget to use `.innerHTML` to append it at your element. And make sure not to allow `<script>`, `<a href="javascript:*">` and any `<* on*="*">` tags.

I also recommend to only implement this once. Either transform your chat messages with PHP or with JS.